# SUM Function Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, sum, report

I will post pictures and everything will be clear to you :

[image]

I dont know how come that 12,79 + 12,79 + 6,80 is equal to 32.37..
**It should be 32.38**, somehow if I am summing decimal values its adding 0.1 on the results, same thing happened with 75.21+75.21+40 = 190,43 and **it should be** **190.42**

I will appreciate any kind of help and suggestion, thank you guys! :)

Comment: Are you sure that your values does not have any additional numbers? f.e, 12.799 + 12.791 + 6.8, which makes exactly 32.38. If your report only shows 2 numbers after digits and there are more, then all will be sumed.

Answer (score 1):

this is because of rounding, assume that the actual values are like :
12,786 + 12,786 + 6,796 so the Sum is 32,368 which rounds to 32,37!!
where as on individual rows they round to 12,79 and 6,8!

if you want to sum on the rounded values, apply rounding before it is summed up.